# What does the error message "Communication link failure (SQL-08S01)" actually mean?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, perl, odbc

Our application is running on dozens of servers and only a few get this error message.  What is worse, is that the SQL query that causes this error message seems to be executing.  The application is working properly.  The process that causes this error is a perl script running on a Windows Server 2003 box.  The database is hosted on the same machine.  This is the SQL that causes the error:

```
Update [WorkQueue]
    set [Status] = ?
    where [id] in
    (
        select top 1 [id] from [WorkQueue]
        where [Status] = 1 order by [id] ASC
    )
```

We use ODBC to connect to the SQL Server 2005 database with TCP/IP on port 1433.  The problem is that this error, "Communication link failure (SQL-08S01)", is being reported about three times a minute.  Should I try switching to named pipes for my connection protocol?